# How to create .exe for windows OS as target through Linux OS?

Tags: linux, web, exe

Am building a Web App.
This App runs on Web Server which is Linux OS. But I want Window users to use this Web App.

My challenge:
I need to create a .exe file for the users who write some Python or Ruby code using Web browser.

My obstacle:
Since Web server is Linux am unable to create .exe file.

Its basically a Remote IDE.

User Scenario:
Users will log onto my website and start writing a script, As soon as they enter submit button, I must create a .exe from the inputted code, and then give back the .exe to them...

Any solution for this problem ? Appreciate your help, and suggestions.

Comment: The search term you want is "cross-compiling" (or "cross-compilation", etc.) For example, see http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/

Comment: @Santee deleting my answer as it has nothing to do with your current (edited) question.

Answer (score 3):

You need a build environment.

One way to do such a thing is let the Linux machine serve up the content and IDE, do some light work like syntax and such. Then when the enter button is clicked, send the script to a MS machine to compile it to a native MS binary.

Another is: to use MinGW

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW

Another option is:

Rewrite your compiler to export to a scripting language. Or compile to JAVA byte code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicholas.                                                 I do not have an access for a Windows machine, am using www.pythonanywhere.com to build this Web app.                                 Do you think I can install MinGW on Linux and convert .py into .exe ?? Am interested only on Python scripts in my prototype. So I just need to convert .py files to .exe                                    Kindly help me,